# You need to login with a user that has edit posts capacity?

Tags: multisite, permissions

I have a network blog and after the user has created a site they are getting an error when trying to save their post:

> You need to login with a user that has edit posts capacity

Shouldn't they have edit posts capacity when they've created their account?

Comment: turn off your plugins and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Short answer:*
Incorrect URL. Was trying to save to the network path and not the user path.

*Long answer:*
I have a network blog. I have an examples blog with the default user. With the default user I made posts. When a new user signs up they get a copy of that post locally on the client side (JSON of the post data). It is a duplicate they can use to get started. When default user saves it works fine because he is at the default network path. When a new user saves it does not work because new user cannot save to default path. New user can only save to new user path.

Default user path:

> http://www.example.com/networksite/

New user path:

> http://www.example.com/networksite/newusersite/

The client side JSON object that was duplicated was trying to save to the original URL (this worked for default user who has same path):

> http://www.example.com/networksite/

Once I updated the path to new users site:

> http://www.example.com/networksite/newusersite/

...he was able to save the document.

The error message was correct. My code was incorrect. However, the error message could have contained more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this by keeping in current theme functions.php
Change your roles instead of author

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    // gets the author role
    $role = get_role( 'author' );

    // This only works, because it accesses the class instance.
    // would allow the author to edit others' posts for current theme only
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_posts' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```

Comment: I don't understand what is going on here. Does the theme have anything to do with edit permissions?

Comment: No there is a problem  with some plugin in your site but if you didn't find the what's the errors we can revoke by adding filters in theme functions.php

Comment: OK. I will check that if problems persist. I think I found the problem was my own fault this time.

Comment: did your problem solved?

Comment: Yes. I had duplicated post to new user but old url was in post still. Could not save to other url site. Replaced old url with user url and save complete.

Comment: Then can you tick for my answer